# Changing Firebase Realtime Database Data Location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I just recently noticed that the Firebase Realtime Database now supports user-selected locations.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0

Our default GCP resource location is in `us-central` region. Ideally, we would like to operate in the `europe-west2` location.

Given the fact that we have an established Database instance, is it possible to migrate this database instance from one region to another?

The documentation below shows a few things:

1. Multiple Realtime Database instances in different locations. (beta feature)
2. Once set, the default GCP resource location cannot be changed.

Given this information, I cannot find online if it is possible to do this migration, or if we have to create the new instance and migrate all the data manually.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specific announcement](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#realtime-database) was that since November 12th 2020 a new region was added: Belgium, which corresponds to the europe-west1 region and as of now the europe-west2 region related to London does not offer the possibility of hosting Realtime Database instances.

Notice that the migration needs to be done manually by creating a new instance in the desired region (europe-west1) which could be easily achieved by using the Export JSON (on the source database) and the Import JSON (on the sink database) on the Firebase Console, as explicitly changing the location of an existing instance is currently not a possibility.

Don't confuse the [GCP default location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0#default-cloud-location) (which can't be changed) with the [location of your Realtime Database instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations?authuser=0#rtdb-locations), as they are unrelated.

Comment: But can we not to change the database url and still migrate?